# Trying to fetch a file from a website, but a delay is ruining everything

Tags: python, urllib

Im trying to fetch an excel file with `urllib` as seen below

```
import urllib.request as url

request = url.urlopen("url").geturl()
url.urlretrieve(request,"excelfile.xls")
```

However, the url is not a direct link to the file, but to a html page which trigger the download after a small delay (without any redirects). This causes the above code to retrieve the html file instead.

I've worked out a temporary fix to this, but it is very unreliable. See below.

```
req1 = url.urlopen("url").geturl()
url.urlretrieve(req1,"excelfile.xls")

time.sleep(5)

req2 = url.urlopen("url").geturl()
url.urlretrieve(req2,"excelfile.xls")
```

`time.sleep(5)` sometimes makes up for the delay and the correct file gets downloaded.

Is there a more reliable way to be sure to get the correct file?

I've tried using `.info()` to maybe try to have the code retry until I get the correct file, but when trying out the code below the info printed is not correlated with the actual response from `urlretrieve`. I'm probably using it wrong.

```
req1 = url.urlopen("url")
url.urlretrieve(req1.geturl(),"excelfile.xls")

info = req1.info()
print(info.get_content_type()) 

time.sleep(5)

req2 = url.urlopen("url")
url.urlretrieve(req2.geturl(),"excelfile.xls")

info = req2.info()
print(info.get_content_type())
```

Any suggestions?

The url to the excel file can be found [here](https://cloud.timeedit.net/umu/web/public1/ri1m5X8Y55ZZYXQv5707X3Y8y5Y57587777QY75Q2Y784X71X87558705X77XYX767Y65678X48Y7Y55516067X6YX8Y0587887907452Y78357X76Y7XY4878889X2XY798Y8Y67YX75X8787851786875X75877757X8839Y7X5578Y8X17Y6W7Y5257X757X7YX77Y757Y887YY75768Y588X275X7705859X8X88785775X879X700XYY0X7Y5XX65787X55Y7887707877YY757588755057Y88708Y7XXY87o87b88Q677QQXqclm8YZ5cZ7c.xls).

Comment: Looks interesting to me. However I can't understand how the _req2_ behaves different from _req1_ because of the delay. Doesn' t both get redirected?

Comment: Can you find the real URL in the JavaScript of the page that has the delay?

Comment: @handras Neither is technically redirected, it's just a delay on the page. But even so, I am also surprised that it (sometimes) works.

Comment: @dangee1705 I have searched for it but not found anything. The script part is 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        initSmall();
    }); 

and having no experience with javascript I have no idea what this means. The javascript file is "min.js" and seems to be a jQuery file with no trace of a url.

Comment: Can you put the HTML and JavaScript in the question? We may be able to find the url

Comment: @dangee1705 Yes, I have added the link now.

Comment: It looks like the js is obsfucated. Can you try and find the URL of the spread sheet using the network tab in developer tools?

Comment: @dangee1705 I'm sorry, I don't really know what you mean. Which developer tools? I don't have access to any admin pages of the site if that's what you mean..

Comment: I'll assume you're using Chrome, so tell me if not, but open the webpage in chrome and then press f12. This will open the developer tools. Click on the network tab and then press f5. You should be able to find the xlsx file in the list of requests and find the URL from there

Comment: @dangee1705 It seems to be the exact same url. I can't find any other url.

Comment: Ive been trying to work out how it works for the past hour and to be honest I am completely stumped. It's the same request 3 times, and it still does that even if Javascript is disabled

Comment: @dangee1705 That's confusing. Well thanks anyway, I appreciate your efforts.